# PHP string with a number range converted to number automatically in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, string, integer, numeric

I have a `php` variable as below:

`$starting_package_wedding =  $_GET['starting_package_wedding'];` 
which outputs

```
string '75001-90000' (length=11)
```

Now I have a javascript in which I will need the the `starting_package_wedding` variable,

```
var starting_package_wedding = <?php echo $starting_package_wedding; ?>;
alert(starting_package_wedding);
```

But the above alert alerts the value after doing the negative operation, ie it alerts a value of `14999` which is equal to `75001` minus `90000` ! How can I get the string in javascript file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding quotes:

```
var starting_package_wedding = "<?php echo $starting_package_wedding; ?>";
```

Comment: Wow..Thanks a lot. Working

Answer (score 0):

Do the **type casting** in javascript as above
var name=add the php variable
var starting_package_wedding = Number(name);